# What's the difference between printf("%d",i++) and i++; printf("%d",i)?

Tags: c, linux, printf, fork

I am learning fork() in Linux, and two programs with different execution results seem exactly the same to me:

the first one has "normal" result, with parent and child peocesses running alternatively:

````
  6 int main(void){
  7         int pid;
  8         int i = 0;
  9         pid = fork();
 10         if(pid != 0){
 11                 while(1)
 12                         printf("a%d\n",i++);
 13         }
 14         
 15         else{   
 16                 while(1){
 17                         printf("b%d\n",i++);
 18                 }
 19         }
 20 }

$./test1.out
``` ```
b670071
a656327
b670072
a656328
b670073
a656329
b670074
a656330
b670075
a656331
b670076
a656332
b670077
a656333
b670078
a656334
b670079
a656335
b670080
a656336
b670081
```
````

the second one , however, has totally different result:

````
  4 int main(void){
  5         int pid;
  6         int i=0;
  7         pid = fork();
  8         if(pid != 0){
  9                 while(1)
 10                         i++;
 11                         printf("a%d\n",i);
 12 
 13         }
 14 
 15         else{
 16                 while(1){
 17                         i++;
 18                         printf("b%d\n",i);
 19                 }
 20         }
 21 }


 $./test2.out
``` ```
b811302
b811303
b811304
b811305
b811306
b811307
b811308
b811309
b811310
b811311
b811312
b811313
b811314
b811315
b811316
b811317
b811318
b811319
b811320
b811321
b811322
b811323
b811324
b811325
b811326
b811327
b811328
b811329
b811330
``` ```
````

Looks like only the child process is runing!

Comment: 2 source code is identical?

Comment: its an index thing.  when i say `printf("%d", i++);` it will apply `i` to it, and then incremement it. The other will increment `i` and then add do `printf`.   So if if `int i = 0`, the first case would print 0 (but increment it for the next time it is referenced), but the second case would print 1 (because it adds 1 to itself, and then will call the `printf` function)

Comment: How is it possible that the same code produces different results? Maybe you are doing something else that you are not showing. Also make sure the parent process is not being killed somewhere

Comment: @Fallenreaper It's a difference story if there is a `while(1)` before those statments.

Comment: @ Danh  Sorry, I made a mistake copying the code just now.

Comment: Not sure whether this helps, but in my experiment, both versions produce interleaving outputs. I would like into how the two processes are scheduled though.

Comment: You missed the {}'s on line 9's while loop in the second program. Looks like a copy+paste or editing error since you also don't have brackets in that loop in the first program, although it makes no difference there. PS Thank you for line-numbering your code; a rare treat.

Answer (score 3):

I think your second code sample is:

```
int main(void){
     int pid;
     int i = 0;
     pid = fork();
     if(pid != 0){
             while(1)
                     i++;
                     printf("a%d\n",i);
     }

     else{   
             while(1){
                     printf("b%d\n",i++);
             }
     }
}
```

It's equivalent with

```
int main(void){
     int pid;
     int i = 0;
     pid = fork();
     if(pid != 0){
             while(1) {
                     i++;
             }
             // Unreachable code
             // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                     printf("a%d\n",i);
     }

     else{   
             while(1){
                     printf("b%d\n",i++);
             }
     }
}
```

Thus, `a*****` will be never printed